# How to display a large number with minimum no of digits using toExponential method in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Consider a number

```
var num = 123456789123456789123456789123456789;
```

When using toExponential() method in javascript the resulting number is

```
1.2345678912345678e+35
```

I want to display this number in the rounded format, like following format

```
1.2345e+35
```

full code is here

```
var num = 123456789123456789123456789123456789;
var n = num.toExponential();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
//n = 1.2345678912345678e+35
```

How can be it done in javascript?

Comment: any tried samples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could specify the places as fraction digits. Without, you get all digits.

[Number#toExponential](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential)

> #### Parameters
>
> fractionDigits
>
> Optional. An integer specifying the number of digits after the decimal point. Defaults to as many digits as necessary to specify the number.
>
> #### Return value
>
> A string representing the given [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) object in exponential notation with one digit before the decimal point, rounded to `fractionDigits` digits after the decimal point.

```js
var num = 123456789123456789123456789123456789;

console.log(num.toExponential(4));
```

Comment: Thank you . This is exactly I wanted.

Comment: @NithinMohan this might be what you wanted (performs rounding), but not what you specified (no rounding).

Comment: @le_m I mentioned the required format in my question. I will edit my question